# Color pattern for pie chart

Tags: javascript, math

I've got a total of three colors I would like to use in my pie chart. My problem is that I do not want the same 2 colors from appearing in a row.
Here's my simplified code:

```
var colors = ["R", "G", "B"];

for(var i = 2; i < 30; i++) {
    if(i % 2 == 0) {
        for(var x = 0; x < i; x++) document.write(colors[x % 2]);
    }else if(i % 3 == 0) { 
        for(var x = 0; x < i; x++) document.write(colors[x % 3]);
    }else {
        if(i % 3 == 1) {
            for(var x = 0; x < i; x++) document.write("<span style='color:red'>" + colors[x % 3] + "</span>");
        }else {
            for(var x = 0; x < i; x++) document.write(colors[x % 3]);
        }
    }
    document.write("<br>");
}
```

Here's a [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fL9sdqg6/) with the same code, the red text is where the problem appears. The row start with R and ends with R, making them appear twice in a row in my pie chart.

What can I do to avoid the same color from appearing twice in a row?

Comment: Your question doesn't make much sense ("I do not want the same 2 colors from appearing in a row"), given your example (where every row repeats letters multiple times).  How about expressing what you DO want?

Answer (score 1):

For the problem case, just repeat the first two colors for all but the last segment. For that last segment, use the third color. Something like this:

```
for(var x = 0; x < i-1; x++) document.write(colors[x % 2]);
document.write(colors[2]);
```

Does this help?